# Numpy: Indexing 3D matrix using 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 2, 2))
indices = np.array([0, 1, 1])

expected_outcome = np.array([[0, 1], [6, 7], [10, 11]])
```

I'm trying to index this array of shape (3,2,2) with an array of shape (3) containing the y-index of the value I want to get. I tried to make it work with `for in` statement, but is there an elegant way to do it with numpy?

Comment: I'd probably do `np.array([arr[i][indices[i]] for i in range(arr.shape[0])])`, but like you said, it would be nice to vectorize that, and it seems like something that would be doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want `arr[0,0,:], arr[1,1,:], arr[2,1,:]`?

How about

```
In [179]: arr[[0,1,2], [0,1,1]]
Out[179]: 
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 6,  7],
       [10, 11]])
```

Comment: Do you know of a way to use the `indices` variable without a for-loop?

Comment: @ichthyophile,do you wmatn `arr[np.arange(3), indices]`.  The key is that the index for a nd arrray should be a tuple of arrays - arrays that broadcast against each other.